# GCC/Clang/MSVC extension for specifying C enum size?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, enums, size

Is there any extension feature to specify size of C `enum` on each compiler?

- GCC
- Clang
- MSVC

Answer (score 2):

With GCC, you cannot specify the exact length, but you can have it take up the shortest length possible with `-fshort-enums`.  Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
    f1, f2
} foo;

int main()
{
    printf("%i\n", sizeof(foo));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc program.c -fshort-enums
```

Output:

```
1
```

However, if you ever want to link to anything, you have to make sure that whoever looks at your headers also uses `-fshort-enums` or it will not be ABI compliant (and you will see some really funny errors).

Comment: I should also note that `clang` has no such feature.  I doubt MSVC does, but I don't know for sure.  It is generally considered bad practice to use compiler switches to redefine the size of types and it is generally best to pack the bits yourself.

Comment: It is better to use gcc's attribute packed on an enum by enum basis. --short-enums can have unexpected effects on headers included from third party libraries. (http://oroboro.com/short-enum/)

Answer (score 1):

C++11 introduced a standardized way to do this, but since this is C you'll have to settle for a more simple method of making the last enum `INT_MAX` or a value thats large enough so that only the type you want can hold it (this is what the DirectX SDK does). Unfortunatly there is no way to force a maximum size (at least not without compiler specific extensions).

Answer (score 1):

With clang you can use this:

```
enum Tristate : char { Yes, No, Maybe };
```

If you want to `typedef`, ensure you include the size specifier for both, the `enum` and the `typedef` definition:

```
enum Tristate : char { Yes, No, Maybe };
typedef enum Tristate : char Tristate;
```

Otherwise you will get a compiler warning.

Or you define an anonymous `enum` and `typedef` directly:

```
typdef enum : char { Yes, No, Maybe } Tristate;
```