# How to specify enum size in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, enums

I want to specify an enumeration size of 64 bits for an enumeration. How is this possible through GCC? The code does not need to be 'portable' in that I am only interested in making the code work on GCC compiling for x86-32 and x86-64 Linux. That means any hack which can provide the functionality I want is fine as long as it works for those targets.

Given this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum some_enum
{
    garbage1,
    garbage2
};

int main(void)
{
    enum some_enum some_val;
    printf("size: %lu\n", sizeof(some_val));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This currently prints out 4, whereas I want to be able to force the size to be 8. Attempting to specify values in the enum assignment larger than 4 bytes cause a warning. For example,

```
enum some_enum
{
    garbage1 = '12345',
    garbage2
};
```

Would produce:

```
warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
```

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6159716/712358) to a similar question here doesn't seem to yield any good results. That is, the same warning is produced as a result of:

```
enum some_enum
{
    garbage1 = 'adfs',
    garbage2 = 'asdfasdf'
};
```

Note: the multi-character warning can be turned off by compiling with `-Wno-multichar`.

---

## Rationale

Since people are interested in why I am doing this, I have written a disassembler engine. I get each part of an instruction as a string. So I want the enumeration to look like this:

```
enum mnemonic
{
    mov = 'mov',
    cmp = 'cmp',
    sysenter = 'sysenter'
};
```

I can then store semantic information easily with some code like this:

```
enum mnemonic insn;

char *   example_insn = "mov";
uint64_t buf          = 0;

strncpy((char *)&buf, example_insn, sizeof(uint64_t));
```

If `buf` were an `enum mnemonic` then we need to do nothing else. The `strncpy` is used to pad the bytes after the end of the string to null characters. If I am not able to do this, I would have to do something like this instead:

```
if(strcmp(example_insn, "mov") == 0) {
    insn = mov;
} else if(strcmp(example_insn, "cmp") == 0) {
    insn = cmp;
} ...
```

Since this routine is going to be hit millions of times, this sort of optimisation would make a huge difference. I intend to do the same for operands such as registers too.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It sounds like you're not using `enum` in a "proper" way.

Comment: What on earth would '12345' represent? A single character that contains 5 characters? If you want to store a numerical value just write it without `'` - I don't get any warnings with `gcc` on x64.

Comment: JFTR, `'ABC'` is some non-standard MSVC extension for `'A'<<(u*CHAR_BIT) | 'B'<<(v*CHAR_BIT) | 'C'<<(w*CHAR_BIT)...` with implementation-defined mapping between u,v,w,... and the set of real numbers.

Comment: @DanFego: I added a rationale.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I want to store the numeric representation of a string as a uint64_t. Look at the rationale.

Comment: @MikeKwan: then your problem is not with `enum`s, but with string `uint64_t` literals.

Comment: `'12345'` is actually a standard feature of the language.  The value is implementation-defined (which means it's pretty much useless for portable code).

Comment: @KeithThompson: sorry, I didn't know about multicharacter literals, this is the first time I stumble upon them.

Comment: But all character constants are of type `int`, and I don't think gcc has an extension that can override that.

Comment: Edited to correct `NULL` (which is a null *pointer* constant) to "null characters".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the warning, what it's saying is that character literals are always of type `int`, never of type `long` or `long long`.

You can get away with something like this:

```
enum foo {
    garbage1 = (long long)'1' << 32 | (long long)'2' << 24 | (long long)'3' << 16 | (long long)'4' << 8 | (long long)'5',
    garbage2
};
```

But you still have to be careful about using little endian if you want to use the strncpy solution, make sure to use the correct shift numbers.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I will try it out later. Do you know if this can be converted to a macro somehow?

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I'm going to accept this answer and do a short writeup demonstrating how to use it.

Answer (score 8):

You could use an `union` type:

```
union some {
    enum { garbage1, garbage2 } a;
    int64_t dummy;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does seem to be the best way.  In my case, I also had to add some padding, vice-vi an anonymous struct, so that my compiler's 2-byte enum was properly aligned.  Gnu really needs to add some enum attributes, imho.

Answer (score 8):

As Matteo Italia's answer says, gcc lets you define a 64-bit enumeration type by specifying a 64-bit value for one of the members.  For example:

```
enum some_enum {
    /* ... */
    max = 0x7fffffffffffffff
};
```

As for your use of `'mov'`, `'cmp'`, and so forth, there is no necessary correlation between the representation of a string literal like `"mov"` and the representation of a multi-character character constant like `'mov'`.

The latter is legal (and supported by gcc), but the value is implementation-defined.  The standard says that the type is always `int`, and gcc doesn't seem to have an extension that lets you override that.  So if `int` is 4 bytes, then `'sysenter'`, if it's accepted at all, won't necessarily have the value you're looking for.  gcc seems to ignore all but the low-order bytes of such a constant.  The value of the constant seems to be consistent across big-endian and little-endian systems -- which means that it *won't* consistently match the representation of a similar string literal.

For example, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    const char *s1 = "abcd";
    const char *s2 = "abcdefgh";
    printf("'abcd'     = 0x%x\n", (unsigned)'abcd');
    printf("'abcdefgh' = 0x%x\n", (unsigned)'abcdefgh');
    printf("*(unsigned*)s1 = 0x%x\n", *(unsigned*)s1);
    printf("*(unsigned*)s2 = 0x%x\n", *(unsigned*)s2);
    return 0;
}
```

produces this output when compiled with gcc on a little-endian system (x86):

```
'abcd'     = 0x61626364
'abcdefgh' = 0x65666768
*(unsigned*)s1 = 0x64636261
*(unsigned*)s2 = 0x64636261
```

and this output on a big-endian system (SPARC):

```
'abcd'     = 0x61626364
'abcdefgh' = 0x65666768
*(unsigned*)s1 = 0x61626364
*(unsigned*)s2 = 0x61626364
```

So I'm afraid your idea of matching character constants like `'mov'` against strings like `"mov"` isn't going to work.  (Conceivably you could normalize the string representations to big-endian, but I wouldn't take that approach myself.)

The problem you're trying to solve is quickly mapping strings like `"mov"` to specific integer values that represent CPU instructions.  You're right that a long sequence of `strcmp()` calls is going to be inefficient (have you actually measured it and found that the speed is unacceptable?) -- but there are better ways.  A hash table of some sort is probably the best.  There are tools to generate perfect hash functions, so that a relatively cheap computation on the value of the string gives you a unique integer value.

You won't be able to write the definitions of your enumeration values quite as conveniently, but once you have the right hash function you can write a program to *generate* the C source code for the enum type.

That's assuming that an enum is the best approach here; it might not be.  If I were doing this, the central data structure would be a collection of structs, where each one contains the string name of the operator and whatever other information is associated with it.  The hash function would map strings like `"mov"` to indices in this collection.  (I'm being deliberately vague about what kind of "collection" to use; with the right hash function, it might be a simple array.)  With this kind of solution, I don't think the 64-bit enum type is needed.

Comment: Regarding whether this could be done with a hashtable faster, I genuinely believe not. I am using the hashtable from the Linux kernel right now. That takes a key and a size of a key. So that means I would actually need to do the padding that I am doing currently anyway. The reason is that I actually simplified the rationale - the strings generated from libopcodes, which I am using to disassemble have space characters padding which needs to be stripped. Using a hashtable would use exactly the same amount of computation but also add the cost of calculating the hash and adding to the hashtable.

Comment: After some investigation, I agree the actual problem is that a multi-character literal can only be 4 bytes (at least under x86-32 and x86-64). I can't find a citation for this, however. The solution by Per Johansson works nicely instead.

Answer (score 6):

Although the C99 standard <s>specifies that an enum cannot be based on anything but an `int` (§6.7.2.2 ¶2)</s><sup>1</sup>, it seems that `gcc` follows the C++ idea that, if a value in an `enum` is bigger than an `int`, it can base it on a bigger integer type. I don't have any problem with this code, neither on x86 neither on x64:

```
enum myEnum
{
    a=1234567891234567890LL
};
 
int main()
{
    enum myEnum e;
    printf("%u %u", sizeof(void *), sizeof(e));
    return 0;
}
```

[on x86](http://ideone.com/TmKCx) I get

```
4 8
```

and on x64 (on my machine) I get

```
8 8
```

Although, asking for pedantic respect of the standard, I get, as expected:

```
matteo@teodeb:~/cpp$ gcc -ansi -pedantic testenum.c
testenum.c:5:7: warning: use of C99 long long integer constant
testenum.c:5: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’
```

---

1. Actually, it's a bit more complicated; ¶4 specifies that the implementation is free to choose as "base type" any particular type that is "compatible with `char`, a signed integer type or an unsigned integer type", as long as it can represent all the elements of the `enum`.

   On the other hand, ¶2 specifies that each member of the `enum` must be representable as `int`, so, even if the implementation is free to base your `enum` even on a gazillion bit integer, the constants defined for it cannot be anything that can't be represented by an `int`. Thus, this means that *in practice* the compiler won't base the `enum` on anything bigger than an `int`, but it *may* base it on something smaller if your values don't require the full range of `int`.

Thanks to @jons34yp for pointing out my initial mistake.

Comment: Despite that warning, is this solution guaranteed to work as expected with my target platforms? Also, is it possible to adapt this to the string/multi-char literal style I want? I guess I could always just generate those numbers, but it's less readable.

Comment: @MikeKwan: that warning pops up only if you explicitly ask for pedantic standard conformity (`-ansi -pedantic`), as far as `gcc` is concerned it has no problems in basing the `enum`s on types bigger than `int` if it's necessary (as you can see I tested it on both x86 and x64 and it works fine). As far as multi-char literals, I'm trying to look if there's some way to make them work.

Comment: If you specifically want 64-bit enums, you can do this: `enum some_enum { /* ... */ max = 0x7fffffffffffffff };`.  Having a member with that value guarantees that the type requires (at least) 64 bits (or that the compiler will reject it).

Comment: @KeithThompson: `0x7fffffffffffffffLL`, I think. As for the multicharacter literals problem, I think that there's no solution.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: The `LL` suffix isn't necessary; a hex constant is of a type big enough to hold its value.  And I think you're right about there being no solution for the multicharacter literals -- other than not using them (see my answer).

Comment: @MatteoItalia. Your answer is wrong. §6.7.2.2 ¶2 talks only about enumeration constants (the `a = 12345` bit), whereas §6.7.2.2 ¶4 says _"Each enumerated type <...>. The choice of type is implementation-defined,"_

Comment: @jons34yp: you're right, I'll correct the answer; still, since each value of the `enum` can't be larger than an `int` (because of ¶2) it wouldn't make sense to make it any bigger than `int`.

Answer (score 2):

[Per Johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622060/per-johansson) hit the nail on the head with his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9524862/712358). As a concrete example of how to use this technique, I wrote up this program (`insn_enum.c`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum insn {
    /*
     * Have the characters backwards because C treats the value as an
     * integer (of size 64  bits in this case). There is no need for
     * a null terminator since we are treating the values as an integer,
     * not a string.
     */
    sysenter = (uint64_t)'r' << 56 | (uint64_t)'e' << 48 |
            (uint64_t)'t' << 40 | (uint64_t)'n' << 32 |
            (uint64_t)'e' << 24 | (uint64_t)'s' << 16 |
            (uint64_t)'y' << 8 | (uint64_t)'s',
};

int main(void)
{
    enum insn some_insn = sysenter;
    char * insn = "sysenter";

    uint64_t val = 0;

    /*
     * We can optimise this by traversing backwards (little endian) setting
     * 0 till a NULL char is found, although I will not bother implementing
     * this till I have done some profiling.
     */
    strncpy((char * )&val, insn, sizeof(uint64_t));

    printf("size: %" PRIuPTR"\n", sizeof(enum insn));

    if(some_insn == val) {
        puts("Works");
    } else {
        puts("Doesn't work");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This can be compiled with the following `makefile`:

```
all:
    gcc -std=gnu99 -m32 -Wall insn_enum.c -o insn_enum_32
    gcc -std=gnu99 -m64 -Wall insn_enum.c -o insn_enum_64

clean:
    rm -f insn_enum_32
    rm -f insn_enum_64
```

Running with `./insn_enum_32 && ./insn_enum_64` will print:

```
size: 8
Works
size: 8
Works
```

It should be noted that this only shows that we can get this trick working on x86-32 and x86-64 (the only two platforms I intend to target). In fact, this trick is guaranteed not to work on big endian systems because of how the language treats the `enum` as an integer value. Also I am not sure that we can guarantee that the compiler will necessarily use `uint64_t` as the size of the `enum` even if we specify it the way we have. Indeed compiling with `-pedantic` will give the warning:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -m32 -pedantic -Wall insn_enum.c -o insn_enum_32
insn_enum.c:13:13: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’
gcc -std=gnu99 -m64 -pedantic -Wall insn_enum.c -o insn_enum_64
insn_enum.c:13:13: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the original question in the title - C++11 lets you specify the type of an enum, and hence its size:

```
enum class mynamedenum : long {
  FOO,
  BAR
}
```

Comment: This answer says c++ while the question is explicit tagged as c...

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to specify **enum** size yet. Maybe not 100% applied to your case, but with this hack you could achieve some target enum size to be cross-platform. You should use keyword `__attribute__` with parameter `packed` to shrink enum size up to maximum value in the enum list.

Just take a look at example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum  __attribute__((packed))
{
  MY_E_8_BYTES_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,
} en_8b_t;

typedef enum  __attribute__((packed))
{
  MY_E_4_BYTES_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFF,
} en_4b_t;

typedef enum  __attribute__((packed))
{
  MY_E_2_BYTES_MAX = 0xFFFF,
} en_2b_t;

typedef enum  __attribute__((packed))
{
  MY_E_1_BYTE_MAX = 0xFF,
} en_1b_t;

typedef enum
{
  MY_E_X_BYTES_DEFAULT = 0,
} en_xb_t;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("Sizeof en_8b_t: %lu\n", sizeof(en_8b_t));
  printf("Sizeof en_4b_t: %lu\n", sizeof(en_4b_t));
  printf("Sizeof en_2b_t: %lu\n", sizeof(en_2b_t));
  printf("Sizeof en_1b_t: %lu\n", sizeof(en_1b_t));
  printf("Default enum size is: %lu\n", sizeof(en_xb_t));

  return 0;
}
```

The output looks like that:

```
Sizeof en_8b_t: 8
Sizeof en_4b_t: 4
Sizeof en_2b_t: 2
Sizeof en_1b_t: 1
Default enum size is: 4
```

Default enum size is up to your compiler.
For more attributes take a look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html)

Comment: This is a good suggestion although it might only work for GCC compiler.

Comment: Yes, the question was asked for GCC. The attributes are specific for a different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhas you could use defines?

```
#define GARBAGE1 12345L
#define GARBAGE2 67890L
```

I don't think you can use enums with a different size than the most optimal.

Maybe try:

```
enum
{
 garbage1,
 garbage2,
 sentinel = 12345L
}
```

And see?

Comment: `#define` is my last resort. I would prefer an enumeration. Your suggestion for enumeration is not quite what I want. I need it to represent a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably using the build system to auto-generate a set of defines. That way, you'll also get endianness right.

An example program `gen-instructions` could look like this

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        uint64_t value;
        strncpy((char *)&value, argv[i], sizeof value);
        printf("#define %s 0x%.16" PRIX64 "\n", argv[i], value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with a corresponding makefile rule

```
instructions.h : instructions.list gen-instructions
    ./gen-instructions `cat $<` > $@
```