# Using C Preprocessing to get integer value of a string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

How would I create a **C** macro to get the integer value of a string? The specific use-case is following on from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524342/how-to-specify-enum-size-in-gcc). I want to change code like this:

```
enum insn {
    sysenter = (uint64_t)'r' << 56 | (uint64_t)'e' << 48 |
               (uint64_t)'t' << 40 | (uint64_t)'n' << 32 |
               (uint64_t)'e' << 24 | (uint64_t)'s' << 16 |
               (uint64_t)'y' << 8  | (uint64_t)'s',
    mov = (uint64_t)'v' << 16 | (uint64_t)'o' << 8 |
          (uint64_t)'m'
};
```

To this:

```
enum insn {
    sysenter = INSN_TO_ENUM("sysenter"),
    mov      = INSN_TO_ENUM("mov")
};
```

Where `INSN_TO_ENUM` expands to the same code. The performance would be the same, but the readability would be boosted by a lot.

I'm suspecting that in this form it might not be possible because of a the C preprocessor's inability for string processing, so this would also be an unpreferred but acceptable solution (variable argument macro):

```
enum insn {
    sysenter = INSN_TO_ENUM('s','y','s','e','n','t','e','r'),
    mov      = INSN_TO_ENUM('m','o','v')
};
```

Comment: At this point I would be writing my own pre-pre-processor. Trying to do it your way is just going to be revoltingly painful. It's a trivial script to write in your favourite scripting language. Assuming your enums are relatively static over time (i.e. you aren't editing them day in and day out) then I think that would be convenient and readable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have considered that, but as a last resort. If it could be done as a macro, we have the advantage of readability as well as being able to abstract/hide this particular implementation detail. IMO the advantages outweigh the option of generating via 'pre-pre-processing'.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible for the macro to handle the variable arguments or it just accepts it to pass it around. See my answer for the 1 argument one.

Comment: @Mike Kwan:  This is a weird way to use enums.  Maybe you should just do `enum insn { sysenter, mov };` and be happy with sequential numbering.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidGrayson: The problem i am trying to solve is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524342/how-to-specify-enum-size-in-gcc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a compile-time, pure C solution, which you indicated as acceptable. You may need to extend it for longer mnemonics. I'll keep on thinking about the desired one (i.e. `INSN_TO_ENUM("sysenter")`). Interesting question :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define head(h, t...) h
#define tail(h, t...) t

#define A(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | B(n + 8, tail(c))
#define B(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | C(n + 8, tail(c))
#define C(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | D(n + 8, tail(c))
#define D(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | E(n + 8, tail(c))
#define E(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | F(n + 8, tail(c))
#define F(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | G(n + 8, tail(c))
#define G(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) | H(n + 8, tail(c))
#define H(n, c...) (((long long) (head(c))) << (n)) /* extend here */

#define INSN_TO_ENUM(c...) A(0, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

enum insn {
    sysenter = INSN_TO_ENUM('s','y','s','e','n','t','e','r'),
    mov      = INSN_TO_ENUM('m','o','v')
};

int main()
{
    printf("sysenter = %llx\nmov = %x\n", sysenter, mov);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This compiles and looks like it might be doing the right thing, but GCC does not recognize the L in `%Lx` and it wants to treat the num as a 32-bit int (maybe because I'm compiling for the x86 architecture).

Comment: Ouch! My bad. `%L` is for `long double`, should have been `%llx`, fixed. Nevertheless `printf()` was just for unit-testing :)

Comment: I love stack overflow because everyday I learn something new! the `head/tail(h, t...)` is very nice! I never knew you could stick the `...` to one of the arguments like that

Comment: In defintion of `INSN_TO_ENUM`, you don't have to write all those zeros after `c`, do you? Wouldn't `A(0, c)` suffice?

Comment: @Shahbaz it depends. Without trailing `0, 0, 0...` the macro would work (i.e. it would expand, no preprocessing error), but the result would be `((long long) ()) << (0 + 8 + 8 ...)` - with `()` inside! - which would not compile. The trailing zeros cause this to become `(0)`, which is a valid numeric literal convertable to `long long`.

Comment: Why it just `A(0, c)`, wouldn't `INSN_TO_ENUM('s','y','s','e','n','t','e','r')` expand to `A(0, 's','y','s','e','n','t','e','r')` already? How does that make `head(c)` empty?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This answer may be helpful so I'm not deleting it, but doesn't specifically answer the question. It DOES convert strings to numbers, but cannot be placed in an enum because it doesn't compute the number at compile-time.

Well, since your integers are 64 bit, you only have the first 8 characters of any string to worry about. Therefore, you can write the thing 8 times, making sure you don't go out of the string bound:

```
#define GET_NTH_BYTE(x, n)   (sizeof(x) <= n?0:((uint64_t)x[n] << (n*8)))
#define INSN_TO_ENUM(x)      GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 0)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 1)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 2)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 3)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 4)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 5)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 6)\
                            |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 7)
```

What it does is basically to check at each byte whether it is in the limit of the string and if it is, then gives you the corresponding byte.

**Note:** that this only works on literal strings.

If you want to be able to convert any string, you can give the length of the string with it:

```
#define GET_NTH_BYTE(x, n, l)   (l < n?0:((uint64_t)x[n] << (n*8)))
#define INSN_TO_ENUM(x, l)      GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 0, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 1, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 2, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 3, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 4, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 5, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 6, l)\
                               |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 7, l)
```

So for example:

```
int length = strlen(your_string);
int num = INSN_TO_ENUM(your_string, length);
```

Finally, there is a way to avoid giving the length, but it requires the compiler actually computing the phrases of `INSN_TO_ENUM` from left-to-right. **I'm not sure if this is standard:**

```
static int _nul_seen;
#define GET_NTH_BYTE(x, n)  ((_nul_seen || x[n] == '\0')?(_nul_seen=1)&0:((uint64_t)x[n] << (n*8)))
#define INSN_TO_ENUM(x)     (_nul_seen=0)|
                              (GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 0)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 1)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 2)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 3)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 4)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 5)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 6)\
                              |GET_NTH_BYTE(x, 7))
```

Comment: That isn't a compile-time constant, though - is it?

Comment: You could possibly make this work using C++11 `constexpr`, which works with arrays too - at least with gcc-4.6

Comment: This wouldn't work in an `enum` unfortunately because the conditional assignment is only available at runtime.

Comment: The conditional assignment is fine with `constexpr`, even recursion works.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, from the question it seems like it is. And the fact that it is put in an enum shows it can't be otherwise.

Comment: MikeKwan, hmmm... right, it converts the string to numbers, but not at compiler time.

Comment: The question doesn't use array subscripting; your code does.  That makes a difference.

Comment: @drhirsch: `constexpr` is available from C++11 I believe, not C.

Comment: The question is for C though. Or is there some language extension which allows use of it in C code also?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Maybe in the upcoming standard. Feel free to ignore my comment and answer, others might find it interesting or helpful.

Comment: The C11 standard does not have `constexpr`.  It is rather too soon to say what might be in the next C1x (or C2x) standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11 on a recent compiler

```
constexpr uint64_t insn_to_enum(const char* x) {
    return *x ? *x + (insn_to_enum(x+1) << 8) : 0;
}

enum insn { sysenter = insn_to_enum("sysenter") };
```

will work and calculate the constant during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Some recursive template magic may do the trick. Creates no code if constants are known at compile time.

May want to keep an eye on your build times if you use it in anger though.

```
// the main recusrsive template magic. 
template <int N>
struct CharSHift 
{
    static __int64  charShift(char* string )
    {
        return string[N-1] | (CharSHift<N-1>::charShift(string)<<8);
    }
};

// need to provide a specialisation for 0 as this is where we need the recursion to stop
template <>
struct CharSHift<0> 
{
    static __int64 charShift(char* string )
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

// Template stuff is all a bit hairy too look at. So attempt to improve that with some macro wrapping !
#define CT_IFROMS(_string_) CharSHift<sizeof _string_ -1 >::charShift(_string_)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __int64 hash0 = CT_IFROMS("abcdefgh");

    printf("%08llX \n",hash0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a C project so I am more interested in C solutions, not C++.