# 4 byte char array to an integer to be used in `case` statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, byte, literals

How can I use a char array with length 4 which is a string literal) to represent a 4 byte integer?

I want to use a string literal with length 4 to substitute a 4 byte integer, which is to be used in this case statement.
I want to write like:

```
case "\x0ATst":
    printf("FOUND TIME STAMP");
    break;
```

not:

```
case 0x7473540A:
    printf("FOUND TIME STAMP");
    break;
```

As the primary code is more human readable.

I searched for "string to int" on google, but only answers like `atoi()` were found.

Comment: `"\x0ATst"` is a character array (string). Character arrays cannot be used as case labels.

Comment: The case label must be an integer constant expression, so you cannot use string literals even with the help of a macro. The best you can do is `X('D','A','T','A')`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I know that as C interprets string literals as a mere pointer to the data segment. But I want know if I could make a complier automatically substitute the `"\0ATst"` to `0x7473540A`.

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode no, you can't, period.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. Is `X` a function?

Comment: A macro. Additionally you might be able to use multibyte character constants - for example `'DATA'` but that might  not work with escapes... and likely not portable

Comment: For example `'\x0ATst'` might work but `'\x0A123'` doesn't :D then you need to use escape sequences for every number there... which doesn't make it very readable

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535409/using-c-preprocessing-to-get-integer-value-of-a-string

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the multibyte character constants may be a great clue for me. Thanks! (Though gcc seems to interpret it backward endian.....)

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode then use a macro!

Comment: "*But I want know if I could make a complier automatically substitute the*" if this worked, what it does not, you needed to make sure the sting literal were placed at address `0x7473540A`, which you cannot.

Comment: @alk You're definitely right. I thought there would be a magic character that can be prefixed to a string, and then converts the string to an integer.

Comment: *If* you are with GCC *and* may drop any portability then this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html might be of interest. Using "*Labels as Values*" you in fact can roll your own sort-of-switch-statement using any kind of dynamic cases.

Comment: @alk I didn't know that there was that way. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch` only works with integer constants, so it isn't very flexible at all. You can't use `case` with expressions, strings nor with any other type than `int`.

But in this case it doesn't matter, because you should have neither form, because neither of them is very readable. Instead use `case STAMP:`, where `STAMP` is some suitable, self-explaining name. It could be a `#define`, `const` or `enum`.

As for how to convert from a 4 character string to an `int`, there's various reasons why you can't simply do `*(int*)"\x0ATst"` (alignment, strict aliasing). There's a work-around for that, by using a union:

```
typedef union
{
  char str[4];
  unsigned int val;
} conv_t;

...

(conv_t){.str = "\x0ATst" }.val
```

Please note that this code depends heavily on CPU endianess, so it is still not very good practice.

Comment: how are you going to use it in the `case`?

Comment: @P__J__ You aren't, you'd use the integer constant `STAMP`. Or just don't use switch-case, they are cumbersome and hard to read. if-else is much more powerful and expands to the same machine code anyway.

Comment: You can use *constant* expressions. For instance `case 3+4:` is ok.

Comment: @klutt Specifically, an integer constant expression. But that's not of any help in this case.

Comment: @Lundin *Or just don't use switch-case, they are cumbersome and hard to read. if-else is much more powerful* interesing theory - the long "wave" of `if-s` is definitely easier to read :)

Comment: @P__J__ Most its a matter of code formatting. If there's just a limited amount of cases, `switch` is cumbersome. It is also error-prone, due to missing `break`, weird scope rules etc.