# Casting enum definition to unsigned int

Tags: c, casting, enums, unsigned-integer, iar

According to this SO post:
[What is the size of an enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366017/what-is-the-size-of-an-enum-in-c)
enum types have `signed int` type.

I would like to convert an enum definition from `signed int` to `unsigned int`.

For example, on my platform an `unsigned int` is 32-bits wide.
I want to create an enum:

```
typedef enum hardware_register_e
{
    REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = (1U << 31U)
} My_Register_Bits_t;
```

My compiler is complaining that the above definition is out of range (which it is for a `signed int`).

How do I declare `unsigned int` `enum` values?

### Edit 1:

1. The preference is not to expand to 64 bits (because the code resides
   in an embedded system).
2. Due to skill limitations, C++ is not allowed for this project. :-(

### Edit 2:

- Compiler is IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM7.

Comment: To be clear, is C++ an option?

Comment: I wish.  I could create an actual type if they let us use C++. :-(

Comment: `REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = ~0x7fffffff`?

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Is this portable?  Please submit as an answer.

Comment: @DanielFisher: ~0x7fffffff is just as portable as -2147483648 is. They evaluate to the same bit pattern. The same caveats I outlined in my answer apply.

Comment: @NominalAnimal The bit-complement could work on ones' complement machines where -2147483648 wouldn't. So it might be a tiny bit more portable. I'd mainly prefer it because it makes the bit pattern obvious, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer I haven't seen an one's complement architecture in two decades, but you are correct. ;) I do agree, ~0x7fffffff is a bit easier to read/understand than -2147483648. Other than that, I'd go with what I recommended in my answer below, especially the conditional part.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I think I recently read that one or two ones' complement systems are still around. But in practice, I think systems where `int` is 64 bits will become what breaks -2147483648 before either of us encounters a ones' complement box.

Comment: @DanielFischer Agreed. That's why I recommend '#if defined(\_\_ICCARM\_\_) && \_\_WORDSIZE == 32' (or whatever the OP's compiler provides) around the workaround, and defaulting to 1<<31 otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately ISO C standard (c99 6.4.4.3) states that the enumeration constants are of type `int`. If you compile the above with e.g. `gcc -W -std=c89 -pedantic`, it will issue a warning `ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’ [-pedantic]`. Some embedded compilers may not accept the code at all.

If your compiler is of the pickier variety, you can workaround the issue by using

```
typedef enum hardware_register_e
{
    REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = -2147483648   /* 1<<31, for 32-bit two's complement integers */
} hardware_register_t;
```

but it works correctly only if `int` is 32-bit two's complement type on your architecture. It is on all 32-bit and 64-bit architectures I have ever used or heard of.

Edited to add: ARM7 uses 32-bit two's complement `int` type, so the above should work fine. I only recommend you keep the comment explaining that the actual value is `1<<31`. You never know if somebody ports the code, or uses another compiler. If the new compiler issues a warning, the comment on the same line should make it trivial to fix. Personally, I'd wrap the code in a conditional, perhaps

```
typedef enum hardware_register_e
{
#ifdef __ICCARM__
    REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = -2147483648   /* 1<<31, for 32-bit two's complement integers */
#else
    REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = 1 << 31
#endif
} hardware_register_t;
```

Comment: IAR enum types are different. see "--enum-is-int" in it's help.
Nevertheless, I could not find a way to make enum an unsigned type

Comment: @lkanab: If you enable the IAR language extensions (using the `-e` command-line option), then you can use e.g. `typedef enum hardware_register_e { REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = 0x80000000UL } hardware_register_t;` in which case the enum will be of type `unsigned long`. See pages 169 and 211 of the [IAR C/C++ Development Guide for ARM](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf). I've added a more detailed answer to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780026/bitwise-operation-with-signed-enum-value) you've asked I think you're referring to.

Answer (score 4):

> According to this SO post:
>   What is the size of an enum in C?
>   enum types have signed int type.

The thing is `enum` types *can* be `int` type but they are not `int` in C. On `gcc` <sup>1)</sup>, `enum` types are `unsigned int` by default.

`enum` constants are `int` but `enum` types are implementation defined.

In your case the `enum` constant is `int` but you are giving it a value that does not fit in a `int`. You cannot have `unsigned int` `enum` constants in C as C says they are `int`.

---

<sub>1) gcc implementation defined enum type documentation: "Normally, the type is unsigned int if there are no negative values in the enumeration, otherwise int" in  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit_002dfields-implementation.html</sub>

Comment: Which means what in the context of this question?

Comment: Can the `enum` constant be declared as `unsigned`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no, they are always of type `int`.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because I thought that an `enum` type being `unsigned int` contradicted the C standard, but I was mistaken.  C99 §6.7.2.2/4 says it's implementation-defined (only the *constants* are required to be `int`).  If you edit, I will remove the downvote (can't remove it now since it's too old).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Thank you to come back on this. I edited by adding a footnote link to the `gcc` implementation-defined documentation on `enum` types.

Comment: Gcc seems to support `enum`s _bigger_ than an `int`: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9524663/318716.

Comment: "In your case the enum constant is int but you are giving it a value that does not fit in a int". But 1 << 31 does fit in an int, it equals 0x80000000 in hex, which is some negative value in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't (at least portably) change the type of enum. The standard is clear that an enumeration constant has type `int`. To get rid of the warning you can use a cast:

```
typedef enum hardware_register_e
{
    REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = (int)(1U << 31U)
} My_Register_Bits_t;
```

**Possible Alternatives**

If this doesn't have to be in a header, you can use a `const` object of required type instead of enumeration constant:

```
const unsigned int REGISTER_STATUS_BIT = (1U << 31);
```

Otherwise, you can use a define:

```
#define REGISTER_STATUS_BIT (1U << 31)
```

Comment: Only if defined in the header.

Comment: where else would you define an enum?

Comment: It depends on where you use it, or you always define them in headers? =)

Comment: `const` does not define constants in C but read-only objects.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with defining constant objects in headers - just make them `static`

Answer (score 1):

Check if your compiler had an option or a pragma to make enums unsigned.  If it doesn't, then you'll just have to use a plain `unsigned int` (or a fixed-width type such as `uint32_t`) instead of an enum, with `#define`s used to define the values it can take.

Comment: Since I'm using the code in an embedded medical device, I was hoping for something safer than `#define`s.

Comment: I don't think IAR have such pragma or option. I will send a question to their support and update