# Bitwise operation with (signed) enum value

Tags: c, enums, static-analysis, iar, misra

I am using enumerator values for flags:

```
typedef enum
{
    a = 0x00,
    b = 0x01u, // the u has no influence, as expected
    c = 0x02u, // the u has no influence, as expected
...
} enum_name;

volatile unsigned char* reg = SomeAddress;
*reg |= b;
```

According to MISRA-C:2004 bitwise operations shall not be done with a signed type. Unfortunately, My compiler IAR use *signed* int (or short or char) as underlying type of enums, and the only option I can find relates to the size, not the signedness ("--enum-is-int").

Comment: Of course I can cast it, I am looking for a comprehensive approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "comprehensive approach"? Like most of the MISRA rules, they tell you to avoid perfectly good code. This is perfectly good code.  You will have to worsen the code with a redundant cast in order to comply.

Comment: A preferred option would be `volatile unsigned char *reg = (volatile unsigned char *)SomeAddress;`

Comment: Any type with a `sizeof` less than `int` will get promoted to `signed int` every time you use it in an expression. MISRA is forbidding you to use bitwise operators with `unsigned sort` or `unsigned char` on both sides. Sounds like a lot of hokum.

Comment: MISRA may be a lot of hokum, but it is de-facto standard in some industries. You may be right but good luck with that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. Post updated

Comment: Are you being required to fulfill a MISRA-C compliance matrix?  If so, I fail to see how the current accepted answer will help. It seems to me you are confusing MISRA-C's concept of underlying type and your compiler's implementation. Underlying type is an abstraction MISRA uses to warn developers of the subtle and sometimes dangerous effects of integral promotion.  In this case, as Serge mentioned, signed operands depend on implementation specific behavior for
bitwise operations.  A deviation record documenting the awareness of this is normally required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [IAR C/C++ Development Guide for ARM](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf), pages 169 and 211, you can define the type of your `enum`s if you enable the IAR language extensions (`-e` command-line option, or *Project* > *Options* > *C/C++ Compiler* > *Language* > *Allow IAR extensions* in the IDE).

In particular, you should define an extra "sentinel" value, to make sure the compiler chooses the correct type. It prefers signed types, and uses smallest possible integer type, so the sentinel should be the largest positive integer the corresponding unsigned integer type can describe. For example,

```
typedef enum {
    /* ... */
    enum_u8_sentinel = 255U
} enum_u8;

typedef enum {
    /* ... */
    enum_u16_sentinel = 65535U
} enum_u16;

typedef enum {
    /* ... */
    enum_u32_sentinel = 4294967295UL
} enum_u32;
```

Comment: While this is true, this is an implementation-specific language extension that is non-portable, and in-and-of-itself breaches MISRA-C:2004 Rule 1.1 without Deviation.  This is equivalent to MISRA C:2012 Rule 1.2

Comment: I don't have access to MISRA spec, so I'll take your word for it. The portable solution, of course, is to use preprocessor macros instead.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter whether the underlying type is signed of unsigned, provided you only use positive values for your enum, because a positive value should have same representation as a signed or unsigned type. Standard says at 6.2.6.2 Representation of types/Integer types §5 : *A valid (non-trap) object representation
of a signed integer type where the sign bit is zero is a valid object representation of the
corresponding unsigned type, and shall represent the same value.*

So you can safely do the cast to unsigned if you want to. Anyway, if the underlying type is char (or was unsigned char), it can be (silently) promoted to int before any computation.

IMHO, MISRA-C:2004 says that bitwize operations shall not be done with a signed type, because the standard explicitely says that the representation of a negative number is implementation defined :

*For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three
groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one sign bit... If the sign bit is one, the value shall be
modified in one of the following ways:*

- *the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);*
- *the sign bit has the value -(2N) (two’s complement);*
- *the sign bit has the value -(2N - 1) (ones’ complement).*
- ***Which of these applies is implementation-defined*** (emphasize mine)

TL/DR : If you have no warning (and you should not for a `|` bitwise or) you can safely use no cast at all. If you cast to the unsigned type a positive value the representatin is unchanged so you can also do the cast if you (or your corporate rules) choose to follow MISRA-C, so you can also safely cast to an unsigned type

Comment: The signess does matter when you use the complementary:
    *ret &= ~b;
(That's anyway what IAR's CSTAT thinks).

Comment: @lkanab For a non-two's-complement machine, it's conceivable that would misbehave: `~b` has the correctly inverted bit pattern, but in a signed type. If `*ret` has unsigned type, the signed to unsigned conversion changes the bit pattern.

Comment: As far as I can tell, enumerators have type `int` regardless of the underlying type. You can force the underlying type to `unsigned` by adding an enumerator like `force_unsigned = -1u`. But, the other enumerators still appear to be `int`s, and actually naming `force_unsigned` in an expression will cause instant integer overflow. (The trick does work in C++, though.)

Comment: @lkanab The signess does not really matter for the `~` operator. More exactly, the standard specifies *If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that type minus E*. That guarantees that if n is a positive number, `~((signed) n)` and `~((unsigned) n)` have same representation. Because when converting a negative value: *if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or 
subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type*

Comment: @Serge, right, the MISRA-C guideline is about warning this is implementation defined behavior.  It is not "forbidding" anything (as someone else mentioned in a comment above).  In MISRA-C compliant development you have to document your awareness of relying on behavior that is not well defined by the C abstract machine via a deviation record, and the MISRA tool should allow for this.